# Does phpMyAdmin only works with HTTPS?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have manually setup phpMyAdmin (downloaded from official site) on my site.
However, when I enter my User&Pass in login page, i get warning:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

When i try same page with HTTPS, it logins. Any idea why this could happen? 
tried `$cfg['ForceSSL'] = false;` but same happens.

I've tried same package on my localhost (where i dont have https) and it logins.

Comment: To help anyone in the future with a similar problem, you should copy and paste the text of the error message rather than just pasting the image.

Answer (score 1):

No, phpMyAdmin doesn't require using HTTPS. Some server configurations seem to be experiencing this problem, which is reported at the phpMyAdmin issue tracker at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14184.

For me, trying to log in a second time works, for others there are add-ons such as Katalon Recorder (Selenium IDE for Chrome)  or uBlock Origin preventing the file `/js/vendor/js.cookie.js?v=4.8.2` (or whatever your version is) from loading.

Finally, there can be some cookies "stuck" between secure and insecure mode; you may be able to clear those directly through your browser (phpMyAdmin cookies start with "pma").